# Run Thin with Apache Tomcat?

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, tomcat, jruby, thin

I have a JRuby on Rails app that requires event-based server like [Thin](https://github.com/macournoyer/thin) to run. 
The problem is the app must be deployed to a Java web container like Apache Tomcat by building WAR file with [Warbler](https://github.com/jruby/warbler).

Is there anyway I can setup Tomcat proxy to Thin so I can serve my Rails application ? Or something like [Phusion Passenger/Nginx](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html) ?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how EventMachine is being used and what for.
You could write your own Webserver using EM:
http://www.franzens.org/2011/10/writing-minimalistic-web-server-using.html

There are also Webserver Gems out there:
https://github.com/alor/em-http-server

I wanted to use some EM Gems in my app and just started an EM-Loop (EM.run {}) in my app, inside Tomcat/Trinidad.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But my problem is a bit more complicated.

Comment: surely if you're deploying it as a `WAR` and it's a rack app, you can do without thin or anything else? What's complicating things?